# How to merge files in such situation?

Tags: git, merge

I use git and my client changed some template files, so when I tried to execute `git pull` it failed. I did changes in php files (which he didn't touch, so they changed perfectly) and few changes in 2 tpl files (which he changed a bit).
What is the optimal way to merge files? Thanks.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: what is your research

Comment: @Pete error: ```Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
display-list.tpl
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting```

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh Now, I fix bugs by uploading through FTP. I wonder, if it is possible to use git instead. What should I do to be able to `git pull` and not to change customers changes?

Comment: Well ofcourse it is possible. The error states that you have changed something in the file `display-list.tpl` And git tells you to either stash the changes or make new commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you are working of a branch called `develop`  .
Now You make some changes to file1 and file 2.
In the meantime the client or someone else pushes out some changes to file3 and file4 to the same develop branch.

Typically when you start your work day i recommend you do a ,
git pull --rebase origin develop
That way you get all recent changes to the branch down to your local branch.
Then you may commit the changes.
Let me know the scenario exactly in case this does not help.

Answer (score -1):

For resolving this issue first commit the changed file or checkout the file on your local machine if not needed. Then only perform `git pull` operation and it will work absolutely fine.